# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined , on my google sheet app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Before this error happen, i've added more column on my Google Sheets from 2 to 5 columns. then this error happen. I'm a beginner with JavaScript and i need your help

Here's my code that contain parameters

```
function read_all_value(request) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(),
     data = {};
  var sheet="Sheet1";

  data.records = readData_(ss, sheet);

  var callback = request.parameters.callback;
  if (callback === undefined) {
    output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
  }
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

  return output;
}
```

this is my readData_ , getDataRows_ , and getHeaderRow_ function

```
function readData_(ss, sheet, properties) {
  if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
    properties = getHeaderRow_(ss, sheet);
    properties = properties.map(function(p) { return p.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); });
  }

  var rows = getDataRows_(ss, sheet),
      data = [];

  for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < 1; r++) {
    var row = rows[r],
        record  = {};

    properties.forEach(function(key, i) {
      record[key] = row[i];
    });

    data.push(record);
  }
  return data;
}

function getDataRows_(ss, sheet) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  return sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 
      sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}

function getHeaderRow_(ss, sheet) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);

  return sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 
      sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}
```

Comment: It is obvious that request is null. Please check from where you are passing request parameter. I mean from where the read_all_value method is called

Answer (score 0):

In the read_all_value method, request parameter is null.
Thats why parameters in undefined.
Please check from where you are passing request parameter. 
I mean from where the read_all_value method is called.